# Convert sequences to Generic Lists with svcutil

Tags: c#, code-generation, svcutil.exe

I am trying to auto generate some code with svcutil. I have the following within an xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="ForsikringstilfelleDetalj">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="detaljID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

I then run the following command:

```
svcutil xx.wsdl yy.xsd  /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

I then get the following C# code:

```
public ForsikringstilfelleDetalj[] forsikringstilfelle
```

What I wanted was:

```
public List<ForsikringstilfelleDetalj> forsikringstilfelle
```

According to the info on the net the /ct option should tell svcutil to use generic lists for collections. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

- To download metadata (incluing xsd schemes) to the current directory use:

  ```
  svcutil /t:metadata http://.../.../service?WSDL
  ```
- To generate the client code use:

  ```
  svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C# /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1
  ```

  Note: *.wsdl and *.xsd because there could be a lot of service definitions and schemes.
- To generate the client code in one step use:

  ```
  svcutil http://.../.../service?WSDL /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this looks to be the same as what I have tried

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji, have you tried to open Command prompt inside some directory and execute the first two commands from my answer? Does the `List<T>` type appear in .cs file? If not, what's the output?

Comment: I have the wsdl and xsd on disk so I just ran the second command, the output I got is in the question.

Comment: Must be something special with my xsd. In your test did the wsdl come from a .net web service? In the xsd did the name of the list have a prefix of "ArrayOf"?

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji, yeah, there is "ArrayOf" in the downloaded xsd files. I am using WCF (.NET 4.0) service to test the command lines. In the generated cs file there are `List<T>` (I've used the second command of my answer).

Comment: Thanks, I will post info here if I find out what the difference is

Answer (score 3):

I may be a little late to answer this question, but I'll leave it here in case someone else has the same issue.

The reason SvcUtil is not generating Generics based classes is because it is only supported with the DataContract Serializer and not the XML Serializer. The WSDL/XSD you have is probably not supported by the DataContract Serializer. Something as simple as having an attribute(xsd/xml not "DataContractAttribute") will default to using the XMLSerializer since DataContracts do not support attributes.

Read the following:

> "In addition, the /r and /ct switches for referencing types are for
>   generating data contracts. These switches do not work when using
>   XmlSerializer."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question is a little old, but I was encountering the same problem and solved it as follows:

First, there is a new svcutil available on NugGet here: [dotnet-svcutil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-svcutil) that works with the newer .net and core frameworks.

Second, you need to specify the collection type you want to use as previous posters have indicated. However, there are 2 important concerns to consider:

1. Specify the library reference that contains the collection type you want to use. This is done with the `--reference` flag. In my case I used: `--reference System.Collections`
2. Specify the collection correctly with the namespace. Remember you need to correctly escape special characters. In my case I used: ``` --collectionType "System.Collections.Generic.List``1" ```. Note the 2 back ticks between `List` and `1`. If, however, you have this command line in a batch file, you only need a single back-tick. The `1 one denotes a generic type with one type parameter.

So the whole command line command for me looked like this:

```
dotnet-svcutil  https://<your service url>.svc?wsdl --noLogo --reference System.Collections --collectionType "System.Collections.Generic.List``1" --outputDir proxy --internal --namespace *,<your name space for the generated proxy class> --outputFile <your proxy class name>.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out why the /ct switch does not work properly in my case. Hopefully, they fix it soon; meanwhile, I added the following powershell command to the batch file to replace the generated array with a List:

```
powershell -Command "(gc ServiceRef.cs) -replace 'ForsikringstilfelleDetalj\[\]', 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ForsikringstilfelleDetalj>' | Out-File ServiceRef.cs"
```

Answer (score -1):

`svcutil xx.wsdl yy.xsd  /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List` will only work if you have a return type of List or a generic class. Check your methods' return types to see whether all are generic or not.